# Error al crear store rocedure sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, csv, stored-procedure

estoy a penas aprendiendo a crear store procedures, estoy tratando de hacer un pequeño proyecto a modo de prueba para aprender.

Mi idea, en primer lugar, es crear un store procedure que me cree una tabla extrayendo los datos de un archivo .csv que se encuentre en una carpeta dentro del servidor.

Este es el .csv que estoy utilizando:

```
codigo,nombre,unidades
1001,notebook,2
1002,monitor,1
1003,mouse,3
1004,mouse pad,5
1005,telefono,1
1006,bolso,6
1007,teclado,3
1001,notebook,1
1002,monitor,5
1003,mouse,6
1004,mouse pad,8
1005,telefono,3
1006,bolso,4
1007,teclado,5
```

y este el codigo de mi SP. hasta ahora:

```
USE [Preba_juan]
GO
|
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ventas]
    
AS
BEGIN
    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF(OBJECT_ID('ventas_units')is not null)
        BEGIN 
            DROP TABLE ventas_units
        END

    CREATE TABLE preba_juan.dbo.ventas_units
(
            [codigo] char (50) null,
            [Nombre] char (50) null,
            [unidades] int null

)

 BULK INSERT preba_juan.dbo.ventas_units
     From '\\dccdt1ssql01\IDCLAB\Output\sql\ventas.csv' 
      With (   
     FIELDTERMINATOR = '","'
     ,ROWTERMINATOR = '"\n"')

END
```

y este el erro me que arroja sql server al ejecutar el SP:

```
Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ventas, Line 22 [Batch Start Line 0]
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ventas, Line 22 [Batch Start Line 0]
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Procedure ventas, Line 22 [Batch Start Line 0]
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

Podrian ayudarme a resolverlo??

Muchas gracias

Comment: Está viendo el archivo vacío o no lo ve en absoluto. Estás intentando leer un archivo en una unidad de red? EL usuario que corre el proceso de MSSQL en el servidor no es tu usuario del dominio y posiblemente no tiene permisos

Comment: Hola, @Alfabravo, muchas gracias por tu comentario. Posiblemente no tengo los permisos, esto lo estoy intentando hacer desmi el computador de el trabajo, no considere que podia tener este problema,

Comment: Prueba inicialmente corriendo todo local con un archivo más pequeño que esté localmente y BULK INSERT pueda usar sin problema. Ahí ya descartas eso... si ese es el lío, tendrías que ver cómo darle permiso a la cuenta de Windows que corre el servicio de la BD.

Comment: Revisa si el terminador de linea es realmente `\n` o `\r\n`, además deberías evitar importar la primer fila que tiene un encabezado por que es inconsistente con la definición de la tabla, y lo que te dijo Alfabravo, sin duda, también revisar: el archivo  tiene que ser accesible por el servidor no por tu maquina local.

Comment: Hola hice esta modificacion al codigo, y ahra me genera la tabla pero vacia

 BULK INSERT preba_juan.dbo.ventas_units
  From '\\dccdt1ssql01\IDCLAB\Output\sql\ventas.csv' 
   With (   
      FIRSTROW = 2 
     ,FIELDTERMINATOR = '","'
  ,ROWTERMINATOR = '"\n"')
END